# Traineddata file For Tesseract

Tags: android, tesseract

I am doing a project on OCR in android for recognize the numbers from image. My image contains only numbers. And i tried the 'eng.traineddata' file but the result's accuracy is too low is about below 40%. Does anyone know about the 'traineddata' file for digits ? Am tried the 'tesseract' raining. Since i don't familiar with training. Please help me to find a 'traineddata' file for recognizing numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to recognize only numbers, then set the Tesseract whitelist value to "0123456789".

Comment: where exactly do I set the whitelist value?